# Every $C_0$-Semigroup on $L^\infty$ admits a bounded Generator

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

I remember my professor telling us a statemen like:

> Every $C_0$-Semigroup on $L^\infty$ admits a bounded Generator.

I currently need a result o this form, so i wonder if this ture. I couldn't find anything about this neither on google nor in my books. Do you remember a statement similiar to this?

Comment: Look up the Lindblad generator I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proved by Heinrich P. Lotz, every strongly continuous semigroup of operators on a Grothendieck space with the Dunford-Pettis property is indeed uniformly continuous.

As $L^\infty$ is a Grothendieck space with the Dunford-Pettis property, the result is true.

The relevant definitions, the proof and examples of other spaces in this class can be found in [this book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GTh7CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%22the+infinitesimal+generator+of+a+strongly+continuous+semigroup+is+necessarily+bounded.%22&source=bl&ots=LFEYC_jblu&sig=-u-LGfIHFX70aeRZfwf40MI6tbQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd2ZOIh9vWAhXFH5AKHbIMC0YQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20infinitesimal%20generator%20of%20a%20strongly%20continuous%20semigroup%20is%20necessarily%20bounded.%22&f=false).